# Using click events on button click

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and let's suppose we have the following piece of code.

```
const showDetails = () => {
    console.log('Show details')


}
const template = (
    <div>
        <h1>Vibility Toggle</h1>
        <button onClick={showDetails}>Show details</button>
    </div>
)

var app = document.getElementById('app')

ReactDOM.render(template, app)
```

What I want is to change the button's title from **Show Details** to **Hide Details** when it is clicked. So I' ve thinking to get the click event inside the function and change the title by using a ternary operator. How to do that?

Thanks
Theo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also keep it simple by doing something like:

```js
let show = true;

const showDetails = event => {
  show = !show;
  event.target.innerHTML = show ? "Show Details" : "Hide Details";
};

const template = (
  <div>
    <h1>Vibility Toggle</h1>
    <button onClick={showDetails}>Show Details</button>
  </div>
);

var app = document.getElementById("app");

ReactDOM.render(template, app);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

you can use the state to handle toggle event in react. I have added a snippet of toggle handler.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

    state = {
        isVisible : true
    }

    toggleDetails = () => {
        this.setState({
            isVisible : !this.state.isVisible
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <h1>Vibility Toggle ({this.state.isVisible ? "is Visible" : "is Not Visisble"})</h1>
            <button onClick={this.toggleDetails}>{!this.state.isVisible ? "Show details" : "Hide details"}</button>
        </div>)
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to use state in React.please read this documentation for state in React
[React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).
here is the sample code to change title using ternary operator in React

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            showDetails: true
        }
    }

    showDetails = () => {
        console.log('Show details')
        this.setState({ showDetails: !this.state.showDetails })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Vibility Toggle</h1>
                <button onClick={() => this.showDetails()}>{this.state.showDetails ? 'Show Details' : 'Hide Details'}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
export default App
```